# Items fetched from api not shown in dropdown react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Working with React app and try to show options within the dropdown like feature, I am using `<Select>` tag of `react-select`.Everything is fine with api fetching and data are available. However, It shows no options in the dropdown menu.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import url from '../services/urlService';

class TechCompanies extends Component {

    state = {
        values: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(url + 'api/roles/roles')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => this.setState({
                values: res.Data
            }))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Select>
                    {this.state.values.map((role) => {
                        return <option key={role.RoleId} value={role.RoleId}
                        >{role.RoleName}</option>
                    })}
                </Select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TechCompanies;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`react-select`](https://react-select.com/home) need `options` attribute.

You can create `option` array using your `this.state.values`,

```
    let option = []
    if (this.state.values.length > 0) {
      this.state.values.forEach(role => {
        let roleDate = {}
        roleDate.value = role.RoleId
        roleDate.label = role.RoleName
        option.push(roleDate)
      })
    }
```

Usage

```
<Select options={options} />
```

**Note:: Also make sure you get response from your API call, to get guaranteed response you must use `async`-`await` to fetch data.**

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-vsi2z?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me. you just pass your array as prop `options` to `Select` component. you can also pass `onChange` handler as prop as well as currently selected value.

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
        options={this.state.values}>
        </Select>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

you can find more about it on their npm page
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select